# Unexpected behavior when passing a bidimensional array to a function in C

Tags: arrays, c, matrix, algebra

I think I've done all good but for some reason when I run the program I have in the output the first row of the array result is doubled, as if it "clones" the first to the second. If I print the result before the call to the print, it is all ok, but if I try to print the result in the function, it all goes wrong.
moreover all the functions are declared on an header file

```c
void product(int raw1, int raw2, int col1, int col2){

    int k,i,j,l,element;
    int matrix1[raw1][col1], matrix2[raw2][col2], result[raw1][col2];

    for(i = 0; i < raw1; i++){
      for(j = 0; j < col2; j++){
        result[i][j] = 0;
      }
    }

    printf("Inserimento matrice 1\n");
    for(i = 0; i < raw1; i++){
      for(j = 0; j < col1; j++){
        printf("place [%i][%i]: ", i + 1, j + 1);
        scanf("%i", &matrix1[i][j]);
      }
    }

    printf("\nInserimento matrice 2\n");
    for(i = 0; i < raw2; i++){
      for(j = 0; j < col2; j++){
        printf("place [%i][%i]: ", i + 1, j + 1);
        scanf("%i", &matrix2[i][j]);
      }
    }

    k = 0, i = 0, j = 0, l = 0, element = 0;

    printf("\n");
    do{
      do{
        do{
          //calcolo coefficiente di result
          element += matrix1[i][j] * matrix2[j][l]; //eseguo moltiplicazione prima riga per prima  colonna ∑[Aik * Bkj]
          j++;  //scorro i coefficienti
        }while(j < col1); //quando ho scorso tutti i coefficienti che sono tanti quanti le colonne di A o le righe di B
        //inserisco il risultato nella matrice risultante
        result[i][k] = element;
        k++;  //mi preparo a inserire il nuovo risultato al ciclo successivo nel place adiacente
        l++;  //mi preparo a moltiplicare i coefficienti della colonna successiva di B per la riga di A
        j = 0;  //pongo j = 0 per moltiplicare nuovamente i coefficienti di colonna in A per i coefficienti di riga in B
        element = 0;  //pongo element = 0 per prepararlo a contenere il nuovo coefficiente
      }while( k < col2);  //quando termino il calcolo dei coefficienti della prima riga che deve avere un numero di colonne pari a quelle della seconda matrice
      i++;  //per andare alla prossima riga della matrice risultante e della matrice A
      j = 0;  //per moltiplicare i coefficienti di colonna in A per i coefficienti di riga in B a partire dal primo coefficiente
      l = 0;  //per rinziare dal primo elemento di colonna di B al ciclo successivo
      k = 0;  //per mettere sempre i risultati a partire dalla prima colonna
      element = 0;
    }while( i < raw1);

    print(result, raw1, col2);
}
    
void print(int result[][col2], int raw1, int col2){

    int i,j;

    for(i = 0; i < raw1; i++){
     for(j = 0; j < col2; j++){
       printf("%i, ", result[i][j]);
     }
     printf("\n");
     }
}
```

Comment: Your `scanf` activity should be taking place in a different function.  Write a function that fills the arrays using `printf`, then pass the resulting arrays into your `product` function.  This allows you to test the two functions independently.

Comment: Is there a particular reason to use nested `do {} while();` loops instead of nested `for(){}` loops?

Comment: @RobertHarvey i've tried to fill the arrays in the main with debugging printf and then pass it to the product, but the array get corrupted after the call.

Comment: @user3121023 it should be irrelevant due to the fact all functions are declared on a header file

Comment: @Bob__ no one simply i'm more confortable with do while loops, the algorithm does its work the problem is the print function

Comment: Note that the posted code shouldn't even compile: https://godbolt.org/z/nPvnEE due to the wrong declaration of the print function.

Comment: It should be straightforward to allocate memory in main and pass the array around: https://godbolt.org/z/5x8WP4